# Make an object a method constant instead of a closure value in JavaScript/coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following JS:

```
for (k in tools) {
  tool = tools[k];
  this["switch_to_" + tool.name] = (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      return _this.switch_tool(tool);
    };
  })(this);
}
```

Generated from this coffeescript:

```
for k,tool of tools
  @["switch_to_#{tool.name}"] = =>
    @switch_tool(tool)
```

What this is supposed to do is generate instance methods for switching between tool objects. Instead of `tool` referencing each distinct tool object with each distinct `switch_to_` method is called, it ends up referencing whichever value of `tool` is left over inside the closure.

What I'd like to do is make tool a constant within the method. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

From the Coffee docs:

> When using a JavaScript loop to generate functions, it's common to insert a closure wrapper in order to ensure that loop variables are closed over, and all the generated functions don't just share the final values. CoffeeScript provides the `do` keyword, which immediately invokes a passed function, forwarding any arguments.

So your solution is

```
for k,tool of tools
  do (tool) ->
    @["switch_to_#{tool.name}"] = =>
      @switch_tool(tool)
```

Which generates the following JS (you can see why it is working now):

```
var fn, k, tool;

fn = function(tool) {
  return this["switch_to_" + tool.name] = (function(_this) {
    return function() {
      return _this.switch_tool(tool);
    };
  })(this);
};
for (k in tools) {
  tool = tools[k];
  fn(tool);
}
```

Depending on your situation, you may need to use fat array `=>` after `do`.